# How do I create a custom Content-Type with Iron?

Tags: rust, iron

I want to create the header `Content-Type: application/x-protobuf` in my Iron web app.

I can see from the Iron docs that [it's possible to construct content-types](https://docs.rs/iron/0.5.1/iron/headers/struct.ContentType.html), but there's no `SubLevel` that corresponds to protobuf.

How can I create this content-type value?

```
let mut headers = Headers::new();
headers.set(ContentType(Mime(TopLevel::Application, SubLevel::???, vec![])));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but there's no `SubLevel` that corresponds to protobuf.

If you read [the documentation for `SubLevel`](https://docs.rs/iron/0.5.1/iron/mime/enum.SubLevel.html), you'll see its definition:

```
pub enum SubLevel {
    Star,
    Plain,
    // ... snip ...
    Ogg,
    Ext(String),
}
```

Thus, you need:

```
extern crate iron; // 0.6.0

use iron::{
    headers::ContentType,
    mime::{Mime, SubLevel, TopLevel},
    Headers,
};

fn main() {
    let mut headers = Headers::new();
    headers.set(ContentType(Mime(
        TopLevel::Application,
        SubLevel::Ext("x-protobuf".into()),
        vec![],
    )));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't read the docs, but I did check the source & it was less obvious there (to my eyes).